# Image Thumbnail Refresh in Gallery

Tags: android, android-gallery

For my application, I need to refresh thumbnail image of gallery.

Because whenever I update my image content that thing don't reflected on thumbnail. The thumbnail image show first time image creation data not the present one.

But actual image contain new data so I need to reflect it into thumbnail also. After wandering this forum I found following code snippet to delete current thumbnail but I can't able to call this function because I don't able to get photoId.

```
private static void removeThumbnails(ContentResolver contentResolver, long photoId) {
       Cursor thumbnails = contentResolver.query(Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null,           Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(photoId)}, null);
       for (thumbnails.moveToFirst(); !thumbnails.isAfterLast(); thumbnails.moveToNext())    {
          long thumbnailId = thumbnails.getLong(thumbnails.getColumnIndex(Thumbnails._ID));
          String path = thumbnails.getString(thumbnails.getColumnIndex(Thumbnails.DATA));
          File file = new File(path);
          if (file.delete()) {
                 contentResolver.delete(Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, Thumbnails._ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(thumbnailId)});
       }
}
```

At present I was calling this function as

```
removeThumbnails(pexelMimics.getContentResolver(),
            ContentUris.parseId(uri));
```

I think this trick will work for me. But this is my guess. I am open to better solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of image saving, I have to provide following code to delete image content.

```
activity.getContentResolver().delete(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            MediaColumns.DATA
                    + "='"
                    + GameManager.getInstance().getSavedImageFilePath()
                            .replaceAll("'", "''") + "'", null);
```

After this I got new content in thumbnail icon.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what class and inheritance you have; if you are in a class the inherits BaseAdapter, then you can do

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

after you change the thumbs.

Comment: I have not created gallery view. But I load image into canvas and then modify that image and save it. So I got latest image but I don't able to get latest thumbnail image.